# Is_template how to add one more template

Tags: php

I have wordpress theme which is adding some scripts and css trought functions php. I want to add one more template file , but don't know how. Any ideas?
This is what I have. Will be happy for any answer . THANKS!

```
// add styles per template

    if ( ztheme_is_template('base-gallery-rail.php') {         

        wp_enqueue_style('ztheme-gallery-style');
```

Comment: not sure what `ztheme_is_template` is but have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

Comment: I'm not coder so)))) Ztheme is just theme name. In this case with page tempaltes array is not working as i understand from other topics. I'm searching for something else. I thought somebody did similar before.. THANKS!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using the default WordPress `is_page_template` function:

```
<?php
if ( is_page_template( 'base-gallery-rail.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('ztheme-gallery-style'); 
} else if ( is_page_template( 'other-template.php' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style('other-style'); 
} else { // the last else is only required if you want to have a default
    wp_enqueue_style('default'); 
}
```

You can add as many `else if ( blah ){ //do stuff }` as you need. If you get above four or five, consider using a `switch` statement.